# Installation problems after broken installation of desktop4shared

Tags: installation, apt

```
ranjith@NKR:~$ sudo apt-get install desktop4shared-1.3_1-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package desktop4shared needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I can not install any software after the broken installation of desktop4shared. How can i reinstall the software?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you check [this link](http://www.test4s.com/file/C48a8naF/desktop4shared-13_1-all.html)

Answer (score 1):

open your terminal and paste this

```
wget http://dc153.4shared.com/download/x3JqSRo1/desktop4shared-11_1-all.deb
```

after downloading that you can install it from terminal with

```
sudo dpkg -i desktop4shared-11_1-all.deb
```

it will install . hope that helps.